# Maven: add external JAR to spring boot project while building jar

Tags: maven, spring-boot

One external is added as dependency in spring boot project with scope=system. Build is successful and when running the project from eclipse it is successful. But when I am running the project from command project using command java -jar springBoot.jar. then it is failed with below exception :
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource

Answer (score 1):

Add below tag in pom.xml. When adding below tag then it will include jars having scope =  system.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this one was helpful